# Notification.requestPermission() not requesting permission

Tags: javascript, events, permissions, notifications, firefox-addon

[image]

The browser keeps forgoing to ask permission for notifications and just decides it's on default. How do I get it to ask for permission so I can actually accept?

Comment: I cannot say this with absolute certainty, but I think this is connected to having a SW or manifest.  I ran into this when building a Progressive Web Application and I would only get the notification prompt if I was inside the PWA after it was installed, but never on chrome.   Dev tools showed the same things you were experiencing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This works:

```
Notification.requestPermission().then(function(permission) { console.log('permiss', permission)});
```

Function inside `.then()` is already a resolve-handler to the promise initiated by `requestPermission()`.

Browsers save your decision for the particular domain and will not ask for your permission again.

For them to ask again you would have to make them forget your last decision.
This is how you can do it in Firefox:

[image]

Delete the permission here and reload the page for the browser to ask you again.

Comment: Thank you for such a quick response; I still don't get a request. All that gets printed on my console is "Webconsole context has changed \n
permiss default"

Comment: which browser ?

Comment: Also, could you please paste the above code directly in the browser console and test? It works for me.

Comment: It's firefox. I just tried it and I get: > Promise { <state>: "pending} \n permiss default. No request for notification permissions whatsoever :(

Comment: I just tried this. After fiddling around it seems browsers remember your decision and resolve your request on past decisions.

Comment: I thought so too, and reset firefox. I decided to post on SO after even that didn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Check the latest answer.

Answer (score 2):

I experience the same/a similar issue in the "Samsung Internet" app on Android (current release). `Notification.requestPermission()` returns `default` but no prompt is actually shown.

This is my exact situation:

- I created and released a web application with PWA capabilities some months ago. Within the app, users can trigger the Notification permission prompt and - when accepting the permission prompt - get WebPush Notifications.
- I installed the PWA on my Android mobile using the "Samsung Internet" app and  triggered/accepted the notification permission prompt.
- Then I moved the web application to a new server. Since then `Notification.requestPermission()` returns `default` but no prompt is actually shown anymore.

My code works as expected in the desktop versions of Edge, Chrome and Firefox (even after moving the web application to the new server), just not in the "Samsung Internet" app on Android.

As per my understanding, if notifications were already accepted, then `Notification.requestPermission()` should return `granted` and of course no prompt should be shown. And if notifications were already rejected, then `Notification.requestPermission()` should return `rejected` and of course no prompt should be shown neither. But since `Notification.requestPermission()` actually returns `default` (I verified this on my mobile!), I would expect the prompt to be shown in any case. Is this expectation correct or am I missing something? Any idea why the prompt is not shown on my mobile in this situation?

**Edit on April 19th, 2023:**
After I completely uninstalled the PWA and cleared the website data from the "Samsung Internet" app and installed the PWA again, it worked again. But still I wonder why the promt was not shown even if the `Notification.requestPermission()` returned `default` ...?

Comment: I have a similar issue, but in Chrome (Android). Notification.requestPermission() is never resolved and pending forever - and no prompt is actually shown.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you are already resolving the promise with the function inside `then()`. I'm testing your example by removing window. and it works for me.

```
Notification.requestPermission().then(function(getperm) 
{ 

    console.log('Perm granted', getperm) 

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/freddyr0/x43j8tf5/

Comment: The jsfiddle definitely works, in both chrome and firefox (this is for a firefox addon). The thing is, my addon still doesn't fire up a request. I got rid of 'window' and the console doesn't even print 'perm granted'. Just 'Webconsole context has changed'. Thank you for the help.

Comment: I just tried adding another console.log statement before 'console.log('Perm granted', getperm). This console.log statement doesn't even get printed. I think I'm simply not entering the function.