# Notification.requestPermission() returns "default" but no prompt is actually shown

Tags: javascript, permissions, notifications

I experience the same/a similar issue as described in [Notification.requestPermission() not requesting permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55095300/notification-requestpermission-not-requesting-permission) in the "Samsung Internet" app on Android (current release). `Notification.requestPermission()` returns `default` but no prompt is actually shown.

This is my exact situation:

- I created and released a web application with PWA capabilities some months ago. Within the app, users can trigger the Notification permission prompt and - when accepting the permission prompt - get WebPush Notifications.
- I installed the PWA on my Android mobile using the "Samsung Internet" app and  triggered/accepted the notification permission prompt.
- Then I moved the web application to a new server. Since then `Notification.requestPermission()` returns `default` but no prompt is actually shown anymore.

My code works as expected in the desktop versions of Edge, Chrome and Firefox (even after moving the web application to the new server), just not in the "Samsung Internet" app on Android.

As per my understanding, if notifications were already accepted, then `Notification.requestPermission()` should return `granted` and of course no prompt should be shown. And if notifications were already rejected, then `Notification.requestPermission()` should return `rejected` and of course no prompt should be shown neither. But since `Notification.requestPermission()` actually returns `default` (I verified this on my mobile!), I would expect the prompt to be shown in any case. Is this expectation correct or am I missing something? Any idea why the prompt is not shown on my mobile in this situation?

**Edit on April 19th, 2023:**
After I completely uninstalled the PWA and cleared the website data from the "Samsung Internet" app and installed the PWA again, it worked again. But still I wonder why the promt was not shown even if the `Notification.requestPermission()` returned `default` ...?

Comment: I have the same problem on the mobile google Chrome Browser

Answer (score 0):

It may be due to a bug or compatibility issue with that particular browser.

Here are a few things you can try to resolve the issue:

- **Update the browser**: Make sure you're running the latest version of the "Samsung Internet" app on your Android device. Updating the app may resolve any known issues or bugs.
- **Clear browser cache and data**: Clearing the cache and data for the "Samsung Internet" app may resolve any issues related to local storage or settings.
- **Try in a different browser**: If the issue persists, try testing in a different browser on your Android device to see if the prompt is displayed.
- **Use toast message**: you can display a popup or toast message within your app instead of using the browser's built-in notification system.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @Abhishek Garg. Indeed uninstalling the PWA completely and clearing the website data from the "Samsung Internet" app and installing the PWA again, worked. But still I wonder why the promt was not shown even if the `Notification.requestPermission()` returned `default` ...?

Comment: sometimes the Cache causes the problems. and I am glad that your work is done with my mentioned steps.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but my actual question (how can it be that `Notification.requestPermission()` returned `default` and still no prompt was shown and do I have an option to handle/avoid this case in the future and/or for other users) is still open.

Comment: Regarding to your Edit in April 23:
I've had the same problem: Weird behavior, partly looking like a bug.
What I could find out is if PWA is installed you have two places where to put notification permission. One in the settings of the installed PWA and one in the browser main app 'Samsung Internet'.
In my case Notification.permission only looked at the main apps setting. The PWA settings where completely ignored. I thought that was it.
But later I ran into problems again. By USB debugging via chrome I could find out the PWA only gets the value "denied" no matter what the settings were.